# Delphi XE4 stringgrid selectcell in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, cells, delphi-xe4, stringgrid

Does anyone know how to retrieve the column and row when selecting a cell in a FireMonkey stringgrid (in other words, when clicking on a cell, we want to know which column/row is being selected)...?

We are using Delphi XE4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the index of the current Row, use the [Selected](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.Selected) property.
To get the index of the current Column, use the [ColumnIndex](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.ColumnIndex) property.

Comment: @AlexGabriel You should accept this answer, if resolves your problem.