# How to unselect cell in a FireMonkey TStringgrid

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tstringgrid

Does anyone know how to unselect cell in a FireMonkey TStringgrid (in other words, i need to know which cell is selected and how to unselect)...?

We are using Delphi Berlin 10.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Selected` property gives the selected row index. The `ColumnIndex` property gives the selected column. I cannot find a way to unselect other than selecting another cell. See [Delphi XE4 stringgrid selectcell in FireMonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17808168/576719)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get currently selected row, use `Selected` property. To get currently selected column, use `ColumnIndex` property. Row and column indices start at 0,

To unselect you can choose to set `Selected` and `ColumnIndex` to f. ex. -1.

Tested with this code:

```
procedure TForm29.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SelRow, SelCol: integer;
begin
  SelRow := StringGrid1.Selected;
  SelCol := StringGrid1.ColumnIndex;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('SelRow: %d, SelCol: %d',[SelRow, SelCol]));
  StringGrid1.Selected := -1;
  StringGrid1.ColumnIndex := -1;
  SelRow := StringGrid1.Selected;
  SelCol := StringGrid1.ColumnIndex;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('SelRow: %d, SelCol: %d',[SelRow, SelCol]));
end;
```